# How To Create Tiles With Custom Colors On Start Screen

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, start-screen

Is there any way to create our own tiles and set our own color for other tiles on the Start screen in Windows 8.So that we can find the applications and files by their tile color and display our files in start screen using our own tiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiles for Modern UI apps will use the background color of the application.

From here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappsuidesign/thread/edf26bd7-0fd0-4cef-bd0f-dcc7399c0f3f

> Your tiles will use the background color of your application.  This is specified in your Manifest in the first Tab.

Tiles for Desktop apps aren't set per tile.

From here: [Set color for desktop application's start screen shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291109/set-color-for-desktop-applications-start-screen-shortcut), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331982/593627).

> For desktop apps, the background color used on Start screen tiles and toast notifications is not configurable by the app itself. The color is determined by the Start screen color theme chosen by the user (PC Settings -> Personalize -> Start screen).

---

If you just want to easily group applications together see this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/491514/85165), on this question:
[Named Group of tiles (Applications) in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/491513/named-group-of-tiles-applications-in-windows-8/491514#491514)

---

For creating custom shortcuts to files/folders as tiles see my question here:
[Adding custom shortcuts to Modern UI](https://superuser.com/questions/491162/adding-custom-shortcuts-to-modern-ui)

> Any shortcut you create (including switches) you can simply right click and "Pin to start" which will create a copy of it in the appropriate places.

So for example, to add a folder to the start screen, see the answer here, https://superuser.com/a/491169/85165.
Go to the desktop, create a shortcut to the folder you want, then right-click the shortcut, Pin To Start.

Comment: But is there any way to create our own tile to show files on start screen

Comment: See my final edit (at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no built-in method for customizing start screen tiles in Windows 8. However, with the use of the third-party program: "OblyTile" (found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865)), you are able to define custom tiles that will open applications.

You are also able to set up shortcuts to folders if you target "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" and set the arguments to the URL of the folder.